# Backbone, RequireJS & Backbone-MVC, MVC = null

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using a combination of Backbone, RequireJS & Backbone-MVC (http://chance-an.github.io/backbone-mvc/#root/index).

But when I'm trying to use Backbone-MVC it returns a null.

Here's a list with all my javascript files

- Main: http://pastebin.com/Pg0s73cH
- App: http://pastebin.com/x4XFxPEG
- Router: http://pastebin.com/0ADCn4SV

When I console log the MVC variable in Router it returns a null.
Can somebody find the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you try with this code.

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery:       'libs/jquery/jquery-min',
    bootstrap:    'libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-min',
    underscore:   'libs/underscore/underscore-min',
    backbone:     'libs/backbone/backbone-min',
    backbonemvc:  'libs/backbone/backbone-mvc',  
    templates:    '../templates'
  },
  shim:{
      'backbone': {
          deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
          exports: "Backbone"
     },
      'backbonemvc': {
           deps: ["backbone"],
           exports: "MVC"
     }

  }
});
```

The shim config can be wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just tested this, but that didn't solve the problem. I tried it at my main.js file, but it returns null.
Code: http://pastebin.com/6Ez67RGS

Comment: Hi, you see this link: [tutorial](https://github.com/chance-an/backbone-mvc/tree/master/example/requirejs). The creator of BackboneMVC did a little tutorial as integrate BackboneMVC with Require.js.